# Meaning of proliferation rate of 3 day−1

Tags: human-biology, molecular-biology, cell-biology, immunology, immune-system

The abstract of an [article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC114648/) in Journal of Virology contains the following line:

> We find that CD8<sup>+</sup> cell proliferation begins 1 to 2 days after infection and occurs at an average rate of 3 day<sup>−1</sup>, reaching the maximum population size between days 5 and 6 after immunization.

What does this figure mean? Does it mean that per day the population after proliferation is 3 times the original population?

Comment: Proliferation means rapid cell division, giving rise to large number of cells.

Comment: I know that but what does 3 day−1 mean?

Comment: Its from math. 3/day is the same as 3 day^-1 (Three per day, in words)

Comment: @skymningen does it mean that each cell after proliferation becomes 3 cells per day?

Comment: X^(-Y)=1/(X^Y). Same way Meter/Second = m/s = ms^(-1)

Comment: hmm also to me it looks bit fuzzy. Did they mean "3 new cell appear per day on average"? or they mean "3 cell divide (and give rise to 6 cells) per day on avarage"? or something else?

Comment: I would guess that it means that each singular cell has an average rate of 3 proliferations per day. But I am better in maths than proliferation rates.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about English language usage.